# how can i fix "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relational-database, relationship

i have a favorite list in my website for the users and they can add their favorite house to the wishlist

it goes well but he can not see the wishlist page and  an error comes like this:

> Trying to get property 'image' of non-object

it's my relations

```
class Home extends Model
{
  protected $guarded = [];
  public function favorite() 
  {
    return $this->hasMany(favorite::class,'house_id');
  }
}

class favorite extends Model
{
  protected $guarded = [];
  public function house()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(home::class);
  }
}
```

my index function in controller:

```
public function index()
{
   $favorite = favorite::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();
   return view('favorite.index',compact('favorite'));
}
```

my index:

```
@foreach($favorite as $fav)

  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="property-detail.html"><img src="{{$fav->home->image}}" alt=""
                                                                            width="100"></a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="property-detail.html">{{$fav->home->title}}</a></td>
      <td>خانه خانواده</td>
      <td>اجاره</td>
      <td>
        <div class="price"><span>{{number_format($fav->home->price)}}</span><strong>تومان</strong>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="action-button"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> <span>حذف</span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Do all your users have this issue, or just 1? Because if only 1 user has this issue, you need to verify that all the data associated to this user's favorites in the db is correct. If every user has this issue, then you need to test the relationship. In case of the latter, you can use `php artisan tinker` and use code like `App\favorite::whereUserId($someID)->first()->house()->get()` where `$someID` is a users id. The goal would be to see if you get valid results at all or not.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that your favorite model doesn't have home relation your relation is house and when you want to get its value you can use `optional` helper function like this:

```
optional($fav->house)->title
```

Comment: And also you aren't adding data to houses to relate it with favorite model

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a relationship with a wrong name. You defined the relationship with name `house`:

```
public function house(){

    return $this->belongsTo(home::class);
}
```

So you need to use this name to access:

```
@foreach($favorite as $fav)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="property-detail.html"><img src="{{$fav->house->image}}" alt="" width="100"></a>
        </td>
        <td><a href="property-detail.html">{{$fav->house->title}}</a></td>
        <td>خانه خانواده</td>
        <td>اجاره</td>
        <td>
            <div class="price"><span>{{number_format($fav->house->price)}}</span><strong>تومان</strong>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" class="action-button"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i> <span>حذف</span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

But you will have a problem too if the `house` relation come null. To avoid you can use the solution proposed by @Mohammed Aktaa:

```
optional($fav->house)->title
```